# Hedging a FVA in practice

Tags: implied-volatility, hedging, volatility-smile

A FVA (forward volatility agreement) is a forward contract on the ATM implied volatility. So at at maturity date $T$ the payoff of a FVA with unit notional is
$$
(I_{ATM}(T,T') - K)
$$
where $I_{ATM}(T,T')$ is the ATM (or ATM forward) implied volatility at $T$ of a vanilla option with maturity $T'$.

How are these contracts hedged in practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than forward start options/straddles, this might help too: there is an interesting analogy between $[S,T]$-forward interest rate exposure related to short $S$-maturity zero coupon bond/long $T$-maturity zero coupon bond position and local volatility related to long calendar spread/short butterfly spread position in [this](http://pricing.online.fr/docs/trading_and_hedging.pdf) Derman, Kani, and Kamal paper ('volatility gadgets'). The finite difference form of Dupire formula suggests the latter relation (formula (4) in the paper) :

$$ \sigma(K,T) = \frac{2\left(C(K,T) - C(K,T-\delta T) \right)(\delta T)^{-1}}{\left(C(K+\delta K,T-\delta T) - 2C(K,T-\delta T) + C(K-\delta K,T-\delta T) \right)(\delta K)^{2}K^{-2}}$$

Comment: Thanks! I almost wanted to ask well how are forward start options hedged, but I guess that would be a chicken or egg type of question.